# Bug in rep recalc?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

My rep tally for Saturday shows:

```
 2     53907 (10)
 2     53907 (10)
 2     53958 (10)
 2     53958 (10)
 2     53958 (10)
 2     53958 (10)
 2     53958 (10)
 2     53958 (10)
 2      9537 (10)
 2     53958 (10)
 2     53958 (10)
 2     53958 (10)
 2     53958 (10)
 2     53958 (10)
 2     53958 (10)
 2     53958 (10)
 2     53958 (10)
 2     53958 (10)
 2     53958 (10)
 2     53958 (10)
 2     53958 [0]
 2     22701 [0]
 2     53958 [0]
 2     53958 [0]
 2     53958 [0]
 2     53958 [0]
 2     53958 [0]
 2     53958 [0]
 2     53958 [0]
 3     53958 [-2]
-- 2012-01-07 rep +198  = 54836
```

This should mean that any of the 9 upvotes that took place after the rep cap was reached should cancel out the single down-vote at the end. Yet even after two tries at the rep-recalc button, on separate days, the score stays the same.

It's not like I need the rep, of course, but as a software engineer I hate seeing edge-case defects. What gives?

Comment: Chronology matters. A downvote *will* be canceled out by a *subsequent* upvote, but not by a preceding one. It has been that way for as long as I remember. What I don't remember is the reasoning behind this behaviour...

Comment: But apparently you do feel there is "reasoning" behind it. So, essentially, what you're saying is that the system functions as designed. That may be. But I feel that either this is a bug that has never been addressed, or else it is a behavior based on a very arcane and capricious set of principles.

Comment: I can think of at least one reason why a downvote performed *by* you should not be canceled out (otherwise people would save up their downvotes until they reach the cap, and then cast them all at once for free, getting an unfair advantage over people who don't reach the cap and have to pay -1 for their downvotes). Dunno about downvotes where you're on the receiving end, but I vaguely recall there being a thread on MSO a couple years ago. I just don't remember the particulars, is all.

Comment: Then I guess that makes me wonder about [this comment](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/95?m=529427#529427).

Comment: Yup, that only worked if I continued to collect upvotes. You have to have an answer or two on the multicollider, then you can downvote for free as long as new upvotes keep trickling in. But you don't get to downvote for free because of *past* upvotes. It's always a bet on the future.

Comment: In any case, it's stupid and arbitrary and obviously may be gamed.

Comment: Why did the "community" bot resurrect this old relic?

Comment: @Mari-LouA: You're asking *me*?

Comment: No, course not. Just airing my bemusement, nothing more. I see Daniel's answer has earned  two upvotes that should keep the bot quiet.

Answer (score 2):

No matter how much you exceed your rep cap in a given day, a downvote will still subtract 2 from your rep.  However, a subsequent upvote will give back the 2 rep.  [Source: MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70158/what-if-i-hit-the-daily-rep-cap-and-then-get-downvoted) (not to mention personal experience).

There is a difference, though, between the -2's from *getting* downvoted and the -1's from *downvoting* other answers.  The -2's from downvotes *to* you can be reversed by subsequent upvotes that day, but the -1s from downvotes *from* you cannot be reversed. E.g. if you downvote three answers in a day, your rep cap for that day is 197 (not counting accepts and bounties).  [Source: MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32569/why-my-daily-reputation-capped-at-199-points).

Comment: This isn't actually correct.  You can gain back reputation you spend on downvotes.  [I took a screen shot of my reputation on a day I rep capped](http://i.stack.imgur.com/aeYls.png).  As you can see, I hit the cap at 13:33, getting +1 on the last upvote because I had previously spent 1 reputation on a downvote.  I downvoted again at 19:09, and the next upvote I got was worth another +1 reputation.